# how to get a value from an object after some time using promise?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am getting user object on an event.
If I console the user._properties.uid before the setTimeout, I get undefined value.
But if I use timeout, I am getting the value. That mean we are getting uid after some seconds.

How can I get uid not by using timeout or interval?

```
   room.on(
    window.JitsiMeetJS.events.conference.USER_JOINED,
    (id: any, user: any) => {
       console.log(
         `user joined - ${id} ${user.getDisplayName()}`,
         user,
         user._displayName,
       );

      const userName = user.getDisplayName();

      if (userName) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          // new joining user id
          const newUserId = user?._properties?.uid;

          const index = participantsInRoom.findIndex(
            (element: any) => element?._properties?.uid === newUserId,
          );

          if (index === -1) {
            toaster('userjoined', userName);
          }
        }, 600);
      }

      setRemoteUsers(id);

      if (userName) {
        setRemoteName(id, userName);
      }
    },
  );
```

Comment: Please provide more code.

Comment: I see "using promise" in the question title but I don't see any promise in the code

Comment: Insufficient input data to give any advice on this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please check now

Answer (score 0):

If you using promise you can call `then` function of promise like this:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //do somthing

    //call resolve if complete with any data you want to return
    resolve(data);

    // or call reject when error
    // reject can pass data or not
    reject();
}).then((data) => {
    // this data is data you pass in resolve function
    // do somthing ex: const newUserId = data?._properties?.uid;
}
```

You can write function get user return promise like this:

```
function getUser() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //do somthing

        /call resolve if complete with any data you want to return
        resolve(data);

        // or call reject when error
        // reject can pass data or not
        reject();
    });
}
```

and when you handle your user, you can call:

```
this.getUser().then((data) => {
    // this data is data you pass in resolve function
    // do somthing ex: const newUserId = data?._properties?.uid;
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: I have a confusion here, I get that we need to use promise for this. But how come I wait for the value to be fulfilled. On what condition I can wait ?